# Call super operator== from a vector inherited class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement the compare operator of a class that inherits from vector.

I want it to compare first its own new attributes and then use the inherited operator from vector. This is an example:

```
struct A : vector<int> {
    int a;
    bool operator==(const A& other) {
        return a == other.a && vector::operator==(other);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
no member named 'operator==' in 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >'
```

Same result with other classes from the STL, but it works well if I inherit from another class of my own.

This is the implementation of vector that I'm using:

```
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
bool
operator==(const vector<_Tp, _Allocator>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Allocator>& __y)
{
    const typename vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::size_type __sz = __x.size();
    return __sz == __y.size() && _VSTD::equal(__x.begin(), __x.end(), __y.begin());
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should never inherit from standard library containers

Comment: @P0W Unless `private`ly? (this is not the case, I know)

Comment: There simply is no member operator== in std::vector.

Comment: The operator you've pasted to us is a free operator, not a member operator -- so `vector::operator==` isn't going to find it.

Comment: use composition instead of inheritance. vectors arent made to be inherited from

Comment: @cdhowie The answer box is below ;)

Comment: @LogicStuff if you're inheriting from std::xxx then you're almost certainly (tm) abusing inheritance.

Comment: Another point worth mentioning, non-modifying member operators should be declared const so they work in more cases.  But binary operators are better as non-members because member operators can hide other non-member operators while calling them from within the scope of the class. (That is, in ordinary class member functions, the existence of member operatorX hides non-member operatorXs that you might want to call.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vector`'s equality operator is a non-member function, which means you can't call it like that. You would be better off doing something like:

```
struct A : std::vector<int> {
    int a;
    bool operator==(const A& other) {
        vector const& self = *this;
        return a == other.a && self == other;
    }
};
```

However, I wouldn't recommend inheriting from a standard container. Instead, you should have a `std::vector<int>` data member (composition over inheritance).

Comment: Very nice.  It is the: `vector const& self = *this;` which is the answer. Obvious when you see it, but hard to figure out.